# What is the meaning of $q in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, naming-conventions

I read some tutorials and finally understood (somewhat) how $q in AngularJS works. But what's killing me is the name $q. Why is it named $q? Is it a play on word "queue"?

$promise would have made more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a play on the word 'queue', but also it is an homage to the original library written by [Kris Kowal](https://github.com/kriskowal/q): `q.js` also called q.

Answer (score 0):

i found a documentation of $q. Maybe it's useful!

[Documentation of $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0):

Promises in Angular are provided by the built-in $q service. They provide a way to execute asynchronous functions in series by registering them with a promise object.The $q service itself is also a function that allows you to quickly convert a callback based asynchronous function into a promise based solution.